# What Language Is This?

Tags: no-computers, computer-puzzle

It is the year 2204, and we have finally found intelligent extraterrestrial life. We are delighted about this, so we asked the aliens,

```
Are you planning to visit Earth any time soon?
```

The aliens speak English, however they love speaking in their native language. Here is what they answered:

```
^ :: ^
^^ :: ^^
^^^ :: ^^^
^ || ^ :: ^^
^^^^ || ^^^ :: ^^^^^^^
^^^^^ ~| ^^^ :: ^^
^^^ ~| ^^ :: ^
^ ~| ^ :: %
% ~| ^^^^ :: ~^^^^
^ ~: ^^^
^^^^ ~: ^
^^^^^ ~: ^^

^^ ||| ^^^ :: ^^ || ^^ || ^^
^ ||| ^^^^ :: ^ || ^ || ^ || ^
^^ ||| ^^ :: ^^ || ^^
^^^^ ~|| ^^ :: ^^
^ ~|| % @
~^ ~|| % @
% ~|| % @

^^^ || ?^ :: ^^^^^
?^ :: ^^

^ :: ^
^^ :: ^^
^^^ :: ^^^
?^ :: ?^
& ?^ ?^ :: ?^

^.% :: ^^^^^^^^^^
^.^ :: ^^^^^^^^^^^
^.%.% :: ^.% ||| ^.%
^ ~|| ^^ :: %,^^^^^
^ ~|| ^^^ :: %,^^^.^^^.^^^,,,
^ ~|| ^^^^ :: %,^^.^^^^^


^ : ^^
^^ : ^^^
^ : ^^^^^^^^
^^^ ~:: ^^
^^ ~:: ^
^ ~:: ^

^ #
^^ #
^^^ #
% #
~^ ~#
^,^^^^^ ~#

& ?^ ?^ # ' ?^ || ^ #

{^^ || ^^^} ||| ^^^^ :: ^^.%
^^ || ^^^ ||| ^^^^ :: ^.^^^^

[^] ~#
[^] $
[#] ~#
[#] $
[$] $
[%] $

= ^^^^^^^^^.^^^^ :: [^]
= ^^^.^^^^^ :: [#]
& ?^ ?^ ~# ' {= ?^} @

& ?^ ?^ $ ' ?^ $$
[^^^] $$
[#%^%%%^^] $$
[#*%*#**%*%] $$
[] $$
^^^^^ ~$$

+ [*****] :: ^^^^^
+ [***] :: ^^^
+ [%#%^^*%] :: ^^^^^^^
+ [] :: %

[***] / [###] :: [***###]
[%%] / [] :: [%%]

[^*+=] \ % :: [^]
[^*+=] \ ^ :: [*]
[^*+=] \ ^^ :: [+]
[^*+=] \ ^^^ :: [=]
[^*+=] \ ^^^^ @

^^ || ^^^ :: ^^^^^
![^^ || ^^^] :: ^^^^^

= ^^^.^^^ :: [!]
![= ^^^.^^^] :: [!]

! [*^}%+**+^] @
! [^ ||] @
! [^ ~|| %] @

(^ ^^ ^^^) \\
([!] ["] [#]) \\
() \\
((^ ^^ ^^^) ()) \\
^^^^^ ~\\

(^ ^^) / (^^^) :: (^ ^^ ^^^)
(^ ^^ ^^^) \ ^ :: ^^
+ ([^] [=] [#]) :: ^^^

?^ * ^^^^^
?^ :: ^^^^^
?^ ||* ^^
?^ :: ^^^^^^^
?^ ~|* ^^^^
?^ :: ^^^

?^ * []
?^^ * ^.%
?^^ ~: % ?? [
?^ /* [*]
?^^ ~|* ^
]
?^^ :: [**********]

?^ * (
      ^.^^^^|||^^^^^||^^^
      ^.^.^
      ^.^.^||^^~|^^^
      ^.%.^
     )
?^^ * []
?^^^ * %
?^^^ ~: ^^^^ ?? [
    ?^^ /* ?^ \ ?^^^
    ?^^^ ||* ^
]

?^^ ::
```

**Question: Can you decode this alien language and how? Besides, what were the aliens trying to tell us?**

Comment: Is it possible you have a typo on line 9?

Comment: Is it possible you have a typo in the line `^.%.% :: ^.% :: ^.%`?

Comment: Is it possible the line `?^^ ~|^ ^` should instead be `?^^ ~|* ^`?

Comment: Is it possible the line `?^^^ ||~ ^` should instead be `?^^^ ||* ^`?

Comment: I'm not even sure what the tags are trying to tell us.

Comment: `no-computers` + `computer-puzzle`... there's a combination you don't see every day

Comment: @BlueHerring - and yet it's quite an appropriate combination...

Answer (score 7):

> Nope

Explanation:

> % is 0

> ^ is 1 (unary up to 9)

> ~ is prefixed to negative numbers

> @ is invalid

> . separates decimal digits

> , is a decimal point

> ,,, is an ellipsis

> # is "is a whole number"

> :: is equality

> ~: is inequality

> : is less-than

> || is addition

> ~| is subtraction

> ||| is multiplication

> ~|| is division

> ?^ is a variable

> & is "for all" (e.g. "& ?^ ?^ :: ?^" means "for all x, x = x")

> ' is "if-then" (e.g. "& ?^ ?^ # ' ?^ || ^ #" means "for all x, if x is a whole number, then x + 1 is a whole number")

> {} are parentheses (PEMDAS)

> ~# is "is not a whole number"

> $ is a character (delimited by square brackets)

> = translates a number to the corresponding ASCII character

> $$ is a string of zero or more characters (delimited by square brackets)

> ~$$ is not-a-string

> \ is a list of zero or more elements (delimited by parentheses; elements may be numbers, strings, or lists)

> ~\ is not-a-list

> + counts the characters in a string or elements in a list

> / is string or list concatenation

> x \ y is the (y+1)'th character or member of x

> ! evaluates the contents of a string

> * is "set variable equal to"

> ||* is "increase variable by"

> ~|* is "decrease variable by"

> /* is "append string with" (implicitly translates numbers to ASCII)

> x ?? [stuff] is "while x, do stuff"

so the final section is:

> set v1 to (assuming a typo here: 15 * 5 + 3, 111, 111 + 3 - 2, 101)

which evaluates to

> set v1 to (78, 111, 110, 101)

> set v2 to []

> set v3 to 0

> while v3 != 4 {

> alter v2 by appending the character whose ASCII value is the (v3+1)th element of v1

> increase v3 by 1

> }

> v2 equals "Nope"

Comment: I don't think your *{} are parentheses* can be right since there is an unbalanced `}` in the code. If the post contains typos as variously claimed, though, the whole thing is suspect.

Comment: @WeatherVane The unbalanced `}` is used to further explain `@`.

Comment: @HelloWorld are you saying the proposed `@` means "ignore this line"?

Comment: @WeatherVane rot13(Ab, vg zrnaf na reebe.)

Comment: rot13(\ sbe VF-YVFG naq ~\ sbe VF-ABG-YVFG fubhyq cebonoyl or \\ naq ~\\ erfcrpgviryl.)

Comment: rot13(Nyfb, vs lbh pbapng n ahzore gb n fgevat, vg pbapngf gur punenpgre bs gur ahzore - gung vf, `?^ * [] ` sbyybjrq ol `?^ / ^^^.^^^` tvirf `?^ :: [!]` ohg `?^ / ^^^.^^^` fubhyq cebonoyl zber cebcreyl or `?^ / = ^^^.^^^`)

Comment: rot13(Vg jbhyq or vagrerfgvat gb xabj ubj gur nyvraf jbhyq rkgraq guvf gb vzntvanel ahzoref, v.r.,  ubj qb lbh pbzcyrgr `?^ ||| ?^ :: ~^ ' ?^ ::`?)

Comment: @WeatherVane - rot13(Rirelguvat orsber gur svefg yvar gung ortvaf jvgu `?^` rkcynvaf gur abgngvba; fgnegvat jvgu gung svefg `?^`, vg'f "pbqr" gung lbh fubhyq "rkrphgr".)

Comment: but how did you arrive at this answer?

Comment: By inference. "First three lines have some carets then :: then an equal number of carets; looks like code for 1 = 1, 2 = 2, 3 = 3. Next two lines look like code for 1 + 1 = 2, 4 + 3 = 7." And so on.